# Get Substring assigned to a variable

Tags: linux, shell

```
bash-4.1$ ps -ef|grep component_events.xml
gdxx1122  1190  1181  0 Mar25 ?        00:00:00 /xx1122/fmw/product/111/ohs_111/ohs/bin/odl_rotatelogs -l -h:/xx1122/admin/xx1122_vmabcd123/config/OHS/ohs1/component_events.xml_ohs1 
/xx1122/admin/xx1122_vmabcd123/auditlogs/OHS/ohs1/audit-pid1181-%Y%m%d%H%M%S.log 1M 4M
gdxx1122 19885 19205  0 08:05 pts/1    00:00:00 grep component_events.xml
```

When i run the above command in a script, can extract "/xx1122/admin/xx1122_vmabcd123/config/OHS/ohs1" and assigned to a variable. The output of above may vary server to server, so it has to be dynamic. Starting string xx1122 has to be passed dynamically

Comment: you want the whole string "/xx1122/fmw/product/111/ohs_111/ohs/bin/odl_rotatelogs" or it must be trim after 'ohs1' ? If must be trim, 'ohs1' is constant?

Comment: You want the logging directory? Is there no better way of getting than than from the `ps` output?

Comment: I am looking for the directory where the file "component_events.xml" is found .. the reason i am taking it through ps is .. the same file is found in back up locations as well

Comment: Do you know beforehand what the backup directories are called? You could use `locate` together with `grep`.   That would work even if the process isn't running.

Comment: i will not know because this script is going to run on many servers. so it will be quite difficult to find the back up directories. That is the reason i am trying to find the file associated with the process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sed`, POSIXly:

```
var=$(
  ps -Ao args= | sed -n 's|.* -h:\(.*\)/component_events\.xml.*|\1|p'
)
```

In effect, that returns the part of the command line in between the last occurrence of `/component_events.xml` and the last occurrence before that of `-h:`.

So if the command line was:

```
... -h:x/component_events.xml -g:y/component_events.xml
```

You'd get `x/components_events.xml -g:y` instead of `x`.

You could change it to `sed -n 's|.* -h:\([^ ]*\)/component_events\.xml.*|\1|p'` to avoid that, but then that would no longer for directory names that contain space characters.

On a recent GNU/Linux system, you could also do:

```
LC_ALL=C grep -zhPo '^-h:\K.*(?=/component_events\.xml)' /proc/*/cmdline |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```

Which would work for any directory name.

Comment: @RoVo, I can't explain your first problem. For  your second, yes some versions of GNU grep have had this kind of problem. Some didn't even support `-P` combined with `-z`. With your version, `\A` might work better than `^`. See edit.

Comment: @RoVo, and you have a process with a `-h:.../component_events.xml...` in its list of arguments?

Comment: no ^^ and this might be the problem ;-)

Comment: @RoVo, It seems the version of grep on 16.04 has [that bug](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-grep/2016-11/msg00025.html)

Comment: @RoVo, I've reverted to `^` as `\A` won't help with those broken `grep` versions.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pgrep` to find the pid and `/proc/$PID/cmdline`:

```
var=$(
pgrep -f "component_events.xml" | \
    xargs -I{} sh -c "head -z -n1 /proc/{}/cmdline | tr '\0' '\n'" | \
    xargs -n1 dirname
)
```

This also works when the command path has arguments and when multiple PIDs were found.

---

**Explanation**:

Search for PIDs:

```
pgrep -f "component_events.xml"
```

For each found PID, get the full command (`/proc/PID/cmdline`), but print only the command without args (`head -z -n1`).

```
xargs -I{} sh -c "head -z -n1 /proc/{}/cmdline
```

Then replace trailing `\0` with newline (`\n`):

```
tr '\0' '\n'"
```

Output the dirname only:

```
xargs -n1 dirname
```